# Using connect-assets with SASS in node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sass, connect-assets

I'm using the connect-assets module in a node app and cannot get it to work with sass using the node-sass module. I can get it to work with coffee script great.

In my server.coffee file I have

`require "node-sass"`

`connectAssets = require 'connect-assets'`

`@_app.use connectAssets(src: __dirname + "/app/assets", jsDir: 'js', cssDir: 'css')`

In my jade view I have:
`!= css('reset')`

I get the following error on page load: "No file found for route css/reset.css" This is the only sass file I've dropped in for testing and it's named per the documentation guides: reset.css.scss

I followed the exact same process for coffee files on the front end and it works great. I've also tried this with the less module as well and I get the same result. I'm I missing a step here? What little documentation I can find on this process makes it sound like a pretty trivial task to do so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What version of connect-assets are you using?

Comment: I've got version 2.5.4 installed which I'm pretty sure is the latest version and the one that should work with SASS. I installed the less module to try it with that and it worked perfectly but I can't get it going with SASS. Any help is much appreciated, we're moving some big Java apps into node at work and all the styling is in SASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, connect-assets 2.x doesn’t support SASS. If you were feeling adventurous, you could add a compiler function for it [like this LESS method](https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets/blob/d3bb9cb29b7ba073fa485f34019ec215296619e5/src/assets.coffee#L318-L334).

Fortunately, SASS is supported in connect-assets 3.x — which is currently in alpha.

Comment: ok great thanks for the response, I must of mis-read. I've updated to beta version and works great. Do you have any time frame for when this might come out of beta?

Comment: Hoping to push it out the door by end of February. :)